# set field value in aggrigate groupHeaderTemplate

Tags: kendo-grid, aggregates

I am trying to aggregate a `kendo grid` and want to set the field value in `groupHeaderTemplate` to something like this:

```
columns: [
          { field: "tupleregex", title: "Tuple Regex",
          groupHeaderTemplate: "#=tupleregex# :(Count: #=count#)" }
         ]
```

But this returns the error `tupleregex is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Very simple you forgot**
 `#=value#`

just replace with

```
columns: [
          { field: "tupleregex", title: "Tuple Regex",
          groupHeaderTemplate: "#= value # :(Count: #=count#)" }
         ]
```